# correcting label placement with psfrag

Tags: labels, psfrag

I use LaPrint in Matlab to generate my EPS figures. In the TeX file that accompanies the EPS file with the LaPrint output, I have some PSfrag commands. If we consider, say, the y-axis, I find in some cases that the y-axis label is very close to the tick marks labels. And in some cases, they overlap. Here is PSfrag code for a y-axis label:

```
\psfrag{s04}[b][b]{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}\begin{tabular}{c}Force $F$, kN\end{tabular}}%
```

where label `s04` is to be replaced by "Force F, kN". I find that I can get further separation between the y-axis label and the tick marks label by using

```
\psfrag{s04}[bc][bl]{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}\begin{tabular}{c}Force $F$, kN\end{tabular}}%
```

where the only change was from `[b]` to `[bc]` and `[b]` to `[bl]`.

However at times this is insufficient. I have been looking at the PSfrag manual but couldn't find any good solutions. Any suggestions?

So I'm basically looking to increase the separation between the y-label and the tick marks on the graph axis. This amounts to moving the y-label more to the left.

Comment: I don't know if this will help your problem, but you could try using matlabfrag instead of laprint.

Comment: Thanks. I have tested matlabfrag before. It is supposed to be more robust than Laprint. But I don't think so. There are lots of things that you can do with Laprint but not with matlabfrag. Anyhow, I have found a solution (see my answer).

Comment: Off topic regarding matlabfrag: if this is the case please report bugs to the author! (Caveat: who is a friend of mine.)

Comment: These kinds of things do unfortunately take time. I don't have the time right now to do some extensive testing with matlabfrag but surely I can do this in the future when I'm less busy.

Comment: and what about using fig2tex instead, that export matlab figures in pstricks? Then you control everything within Latex.

Comment: I have never used fig2tex before. I am looking at it right now and was wondering if it is mainly for line drawings. What about its suitability for bifurcation diagrams where we have dense points? You can see a bifurcation diagram here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:LogisticMap_BifurcationDiagram.png

I have actually denser regions than what the above example provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution by modifying the `\arraystretch` parameter. It works fine.

e.g.

```
\psfrag{s04}[bc][bl]{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}\begin{tabular}{c}Write here\end{tabular}}%
```

Comment: I'm accepting my own answer for now but others are welcome to post other solutions for this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the replacement into `\raisebox{±voffset}{...}` for vertical displacement and prepend `\hspace{±hoffset}` for horizontal shifting.

Answer (score 1):

I use [struts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strut_%28typesetting%29), or phantom objects, which is ugly but which does the trick. Thus, you might include `\phantom{a}` or something before the text in order to force the text to the right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I apply your technique to the y axis label, then the label moves upwards. What I want is to increase the separation between the label and the tickmarks i.e. make the label move to the left with respect to the y axis.

Comment: Then add phontom characters after the text.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried this. But adding phantom characters may not be an elegant solution. With the \arraystretch command, I have just 1 parameter to play with (see my extended answer) and I think it's less messy than using phantom characters. But I know that phantom characters are very useful: I have indeed used them before in other LaTeX documents :).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most general solution is to use a zero sized `picture` environment containing a `\put` you can then place the LaTeX text at any coordinate offset.