# Why does the ```\vspace``` command not work with PSfrag?

Tags: eps, psfrag, vspace

When loading in eps graphs, I wanted to shift the positions of the axis labels, and I found I could achieve that with PSfrag (something like `\psfrag{label}{\hspace{1em}label}`).  I've found that this works with `\hspace` but not `\vspace`.  I now know that instead of `\vspace`, I should use `\raisebox{1em}{label}`, [thanks to this lovely answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127213/169733).  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A psfrag replacement is essentially set in an `\mbox` so a horizontal mode construct. As always in such a construct, vertical mode material doesn't work, although you could nest a `\parbox` to get into vertical mode and add a vertical material. or more simply you could use `\raisebox{10pt}{...}` rather than using `\vspace`